# Exponential distribution for the lifetime of an LCD screen: probability that it functions for $50{,}000$ hours

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

If the probability that an LCD screen functions for $x$ hours is defined by the density function:

$$f(x)=0.01*\exp(-x/100)I_{[0,\infty)}(x)$$

where $I$ is an indicator function and $x$ is measured in thousands of hours, then the probability that the screen functions for $50{,}000$ hours is given by:

$$P(50)= \int_{50}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx = 0.6065$$

So the only event $x=50$ is considered as the interval $[50,\infty)$, right? Because if we integrate the event $x=50$, $\int_{50}^{50} f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ will always be $0$.

Comment: I thank you very much Mr.Lord Farin for beautifully editing my question !

Comment: My pleasure :). For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: Why is 50,000 replaced by 50?

Comment: Because x is measured in thoundsands of hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the lifetime of a screen, in thousands of hours. We are told that $X$ has density function $(0.01)e^{-x/100}$ in the interval $[0,\infty)$, and $0$ elsewhere. Then
$$\Pr(X\gt 50)=\int_{50}^\infty (0.01)e^{-x/100}\,dx.$$
This is approximately $0.60653$.

Note that $\Pr(X\gt 50)=\Pr(X\ge 50)$. For any random variable $X$ with **continuous** distribution, $\Pr(X=a)=0$ for any $a$.

Comment: If so, any probability of elementary event of continuous case will always be 0. This is strange without making assumptions.

Comment: Yes, it will be $0$. Maybe you will view it as less strange if you take into account the fact that this model of LCD screen lifetime is a **mathematical model**, not the reality. With probability models, we can expect at most a modestly good fit with reality. I would expect that in this case the fit is not even particularly good. The exponential distribution is **memoryless**: objects die but do not age. Under that model, a $100000$-hour old LCD has just the same probability of surviving another $50000$ hours as a brand new LCD.

Comment: Is this means that there is no way to calculate exactly an elementary event in continuous case?

Comment: Also, a fair number of LCD fail early, much earlier than an exponential model would suggest. There has been a fair amount of work done on good models for the lifetime of various electronic components. The exponential type model is very crude.

Comment: There is a way to calculate $\Pr(X=a)$: it is $0$. But we are primarily interested in the probabilities of genuine intervals, and boolean combinations thereof.

Comment: I thank you for your dedication. This is just one of the very basic exercises in chapter 2 from Ron Mittelhammer Mathematical Statistics for Economics and Business, and it seems that the solution of that exercise presume that P(50) is considered to be P(x>=50).

Comment: Unfortunate! it becomes quite difficult for students when a book or course uses non-standard notation. Everything is fine *within* the course, but then there is puzzlement when one meets external material.

Comment: Maybe it is the typos of the book. Maybe the problem tells us to calculate P(X>50).